# Pros and Cons of using a method versus a constant for Ruby string declaration

Tags: ruby, methods, constants

I want to designate some strings that won't change in a Ruby class. When should I use a constant vs a method?

```
class ApiWrapper
  # option 1
  PATH = "/posts"

  # option 2
  def self.path
    "/posts"
  end

  def get_posts
    Net::HTTP.get('blogpostworld.com', ApiWrapper::PATH)
    # vs
    Net::HTTP.get('blogpostworld.com', ApiWrapper.path)
  end
end
```

Accessing these is the difference between `ApiWrapper::PATH` vs `ApiWrapper.path`

Usage would look like:

```
wrapper = ApiWrapper.new(config)
response = wrapper.get_posts
```

When would I favor one option over the other?

Personally I like the method option, especially if it is declared as private:

```
class ApiWrapper
  # ... initializer stuff

  def get_posts
    Net::HTTP.get('blogpostworld.com', ApiWrapper.path)
  end

  private_class_method def self.path
    "/posts"
  end
end
```

Comment: With constants, you don't need the FQN here. Can refer to it as simply `PATH`.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a definitive answer, but consider:

```
ApiWrapper::PATH << "1"
p ApiWrapper::PATH
#=> "/posts1"

ApiWrapper.path << "1"
p ApiWrapper.path
#=> "/posts"
```

Unless you freeze the `Constant`:

```
class ApiWrapper
  PATH = "/posts".freeze
end

ApiWrapper::PATH << "1"
#=> can't modify frozen String (FrozenError)
```

And `ApiWrapper::PATH` looks like a constant, `ApiWrapper.path` doesn't.

Comment: i was debating adding a `.freeze` but didn't think it was related to my question regarding constant vs method. Let's say I add the freeze, what should I be concerned with then?

Answer (score 2):

Here some thoughts from my experience.

### Method approach:

- When using a [template method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).
- When you want to keep that constant private and you don't use `private_constant` explicitly ([docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Module.html#method-i-private_constant)). This can be helpful to prevent coupling from other modules.
- When the value is expected to change at some point in the future but you don't want to modify the signature of the method (thinking of a gem).

### Constant approach:

- When you want to make the value public (can also be achieved with a public class method).
- When you want to make explicit that the value is going to remain the same through the execution (as @iGian mentioned in his answer).

However, in most of the cases I would say it's OK using any of the approaches and switch to one of them if needed.